# LinkedList Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, gcc

This LinkedList Checkbook program I wrote keeps getting a segmentation fault, and won't display the dates of my checks? I've been trying to debug but can't find the spot where I made a mistake. The program runs correctly except than when it displays a check from the checkbook, it doesn't display the date that the user inputs when creating a new check. When selecting the option to view a specific check, the program gets a segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/*
 * The purpose of this program is to use a linked list in a C program.
 * Date Created: 8 March 2020
 */

/*
 * Variable to track items and clear the buffer
 */
char temp [50];

/* Check structure */
struct check {
    int num;
    char date[30];
    char to[30];
    float amount;
    char descrip[30];
    struct check *next;
};

/* Linked list of checks (checkbook) */
struct check *checkbook = NULL;

/* Keep track of last node, last check in the book */
struct check *last = NULL;

/* Function declarations */
void addCheck(); //Add a check to the checkbook
void deleteCheck(int chkNum); //Delete a check from the checkbook
void showCheck(struct check *thisCheck); //show the desired check
void showCheckbook(); //show the entire checkbook
void showSpecificCheck(int chkNum); //show a specific check to the user

/** FUNCTIONS **/

/* Adds a check to the checkbook */
void addCheck() {

    /* Creates new node and memory for the node. */
    struct check *newNode = (struct check *)malloc(sizeof(struct check));

    /* Sets the number of the check */
    if (last == NULL) {
        newNode -> num = 1;
    } else {
        newNode -> num = last -> num + 1;
    }

    /* Get user input for the check */

    printf("Enter the number of the check: ");
    scanf("%d", &newNode -> num);

    printf("Enter the date in dd/mm/yy format: ");
    fgets(newNode -> date, 30, stdin);

    /* Removes extra newline */
    fgets(temp, 50, stdin);

    printf("Enter the recipient: ");
    fgets(newNode -> to, 30, stdin);

    printf("Enter the amount in decimal form: ");
    scanf("%f", &newNode -> amount);

    /* Removes extra newline */
    fgets(temp, 50, stdin);

    printf("Enter a description: ");
    fgets(newNode -> descrip, 30, stdin);

    /* Print check info */
    printf("--------------------\n");
    printf("Check Number: %d\n", newNode -> num);
    printf("Date: %s", newNode -> date);
    printf("To: %s", newNode -> to);
    printf("Amount: %.2f\n", newNode -> amount);
    printf("Description: %s", newNode -> descrip);
    printf("--------------------\n");

    if (checkbook == NULL) {
        checkbook = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    } else {
        last -> next = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }
}

/* Deleting a check */
void deleteCheck(int chkNum) {

    struct check *temp = checkbook;
    struct check *del = NULL;

    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Check %d was not found. \n", chkNum);
    }

    if(chkNum == 1) {
        checkbook = temp -> next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < chkNum-2;i++)
        temp = temp -> next; //temp points to the n-1th node in the list
    del = temp -> next; //nth node
    temp -> next = del -> next; //n-1th node
    free(del); //delete del
}


/* Show a specific check */
void showSpecificCheck(int chkNum) {

    struct check *temp = checkbook;
    struct check *del = NULL;

    /* Empty list */
    if (temp = NULL) {
        printf("Check %d was not found. \n", chkNum);
    }
    /* First node */
    else if (temp -> num == chkNum) {
        showCheck(temp);
    }
    /* Other node */
    else {
        while (temp != NULL) {
            /* Number is not in list */
            if (temp -> next == NULL) {
                printf("Check %d was not found. \n", chkNum);
                break;
            }
            /* if number is found */
            else {
                showCheck(temp -> next);
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Show Check Function
 * @param the check to diplay
 */
void showCheck(struct check *thisCheck) {

    printf("--------------------\n");
    printf("Check #: %d\n", thisCheck -> num);
    printf("Date: %s\n", thisCheck -> date);
    printf("To: %s\n", thisCheck -> to);
    printf("Amount: %.2f\n", thisCheck -> amount);
    printf("Description: %s\n", thisCheck -> descrip);
    printf("--------------------\n");

}

/*
 * Show Checkbook Function
 */
void showCheckbook() {
    struct check *current = checkbook;

    while (current != NULL) {
        showCheck(current);
        current = current -> next;
    }
}

/*
 * Main function
 */
int main() {

    /* Keeps the user choice displayed */
    char choice = ' ';

    /* Displays greeting */
    printf("Aloha and welcome to your checkbook! Please select one of the options below: \n");

    /* Continues to run program while user does not want to exit */
    while ( choice != 'e') {

        /* Display selection options to the user */
        printf("Press 'a' to add a new check \n");
        printf("Press 'v' to view your checkbook \n");
        printf("Press 'c' to view a specific check \n");
        printf("Press 'd' to delete a specific check \n");
        printf("Press 'e' to exit the program \n\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: \n");

        /* Gets the user choice */
        scanf("%c", &choice);

        if (choice == 'a' ) {
            addCheck();
        }

        else if (choice == 'v') {
            showCheckbook();
            /* Removes extra newline */
            fgets(temp, 50, stdin);
        }

        else if (choice == 'c') {
            int i;
            printf("Enter the check number: \n");
            scanf(" %d", &i);
            showSpecificCheck(i);

            /* Removes extra newline */
            fgets(temp, 50, stdin);
        }

        else if (choice == 'd') {
            int j;
            printf("Enter the number of the check you want to delete: \n");
            scanf(" %d", &j);
            deleteCheck(j);

            /* Removes extra newline */
            fgets(temp, 50, stdin);
        }

        else if (choice == 'e') {
            printf("Mahalo for using your checkbook. Have a great day!");
        }

        else {
            printf("You must enter one of the selected options above.");
        }
    }

    return(0);          

}
```

Comment: How have you been trying to debug? A debugger will at the very minimum tell you immediately which exact line of code triggers the seg fault. And much more. have you been using a debugger?

Comment: No, I've been doing it manually since I don't have an IDE set up on my current device yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `showSpecificCheckIn()`, the piece of code

```
//...
if (temp = NULL) {
         ^
    printf("Check %d was not found. \n", chkNum)
//...
```

the condition will always evaluate to true, what you need is

```
if (temp == NULL) {
         ^^
    printf("Check %d was not found. \n", chkNum);
```

That will fix the segfault.

The date issue is because as you read date input there is a lingering `'\n'` character int the `stdin` buffer, so `fgets()` will catch it and leave the inputed date in the buffer wich will be read by the next `fgets()` and so on, derailing all your reads, that's why you felt the need to use

```
/* Removes extra newline */
fgets(temp, 50, stdin);
```

to clear the buffer.

That, however, doesn't solve the fact that the date field remains empty (with a `'\n'` character, that is) to fix this just place `getchar();` before `fgets(newNode->date, 30, stdin);`, you can then remove `fgets(temp, 50, stdin);`

Your date will be properly read and the buffer will be emptied.

[**Link to live sample here**](https://onlinegdb.com/Sy4Fa05BU)

Other than that, there is a `del` variable unused in your `deleteCheck()` function, you might want to check that out.